# Running pod install on jenkins in a Mac mini machine gives error

Tags: macos, jenkins, cocoapods

I have a Jenkins setup in a mac mini to build my IOS application automatically.

When running `pod install` on a job, cocoapods throw an error :

`/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:439:in help!': [!] You cannot run CocoaPods as root. (CLAide::Help)`

I've tried to pass the option command `--allow root, but it keeps giving me the same error.

Comment: If that message asks you to use another user, why not use another (non-root) user?

Comment: You're talking about the jenkins_user, that's is created when you set up your jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs when running `sudo brew services start jenkins-lts`.

Running only `brew services start jenkins-lts` , solves the issue